# Javascript/jQuery set variable to object property for multiple $.ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am looking to send a number of different queries via $.ajax as JSON.

I have stored these queries in an object using the following:

```
var objectName = { 
"name1": { 
    "queryName": "longname1", 
    "queryAction": "JSONtoSend" 
}, 
"name2": { 
    "queryName": "longname2", 
    "queryAction": "JSONtoSend" 
},  
};
```

I am then going through the queryActions and setting them:

```
for (var i = 0, len = Object.keys(objectName).length; i < len; ++i) {
    var indexName = Object.keys(objectName)[i];
    objectName[indexName].queryAction = "";

    var JSONtoTransfer = objectName[indexName].queryAction;
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'URL',
    data: JSONtoTransfer,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(dataReturn){
        alert(dataReturn.blah);
    }
});
```

I am unable to set the var JSONtoTransfer. It gives me an unexpected [ error. How do I get around this? I get the same error if I enter it straight into the data parameter of $.ajax.

The code I am using is storing the queries in the object correctly, but I need a way to iterate through them all and send via $.ajax.

Thank you for the help. This code is probably not the most efficient way of doing things, so if anyone has any advice, it's more than welcome too :-)

So I wrote the original code wrong, the $.ajax call should be included in the for statement. So it actually iterates....

Anyway, what I found to work was creating an array, pushing the queryAction into it and then stringifying it...

Comment: You have to define the JSONtoTransfer variable before you loop through the object: var JSONtoTransfer = [];  for(...) { JSONtoTransfer.push(objectName[indexName].queryAction); }

Comment: Why are you setting `objectName[indexName].queryAction = "";`?

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm not, it would be a string/JSON.

Comment: @SimonHarper your code doesn't make much sense to me... Even that, surely your `"JSONtoSend"` isn't valid json

Comment: It's not clear enough to understand what you want to send. Is it a string? Do you want the  objectName.keys to be the POST parameters?

Comment: @Spokey - the request works when I send a JSON as a string, so I am looking to store these various requests within the object. The reason I am looking to iterate is because the only difference between the request strings is the 'longName' value and a date value. I want the $.ajax data to be what is contained within the objectName.name.queryAction.

Comment: @Zaggo0 - This works, except now the data being is in the following format->  0: 'query' when I just want the query. Actually, that's after it's been parsed in Chrome. Before it's been parsed, it is showing with [] around it.

Comment: @Zagg0 It now works, simply by using toString, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems:

- `JSONtoTransfer` is out of scope of your ajax call. If you want to populate `JSONtoTransfer` on every iteration and make an ajax request with this different value each time - put the ajax call inside the for loop (although I would seriously consider refactoring this so that you make one ajax call, and deserialize it differently (if it's your server-side code handling it))
- You're setting `objectName[indexName].queryAction` to an empty string, then assigning this value to `JSONtoTransfer` (now always going to be an empty string)
- You have your `for` syntax a bit muddled up. Best practice would be to change

  `for (var i = 0, len = Object.keys(objectName).length; i < len; ++i) {`

  to

  `for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(objectName).length; ++i) {`

  i.e. there's no need to keep initialising `len` to the same value. NOTE: This is more for readability, not (so much) performance. If you had another use for `len` inside the loop this advice wouldn't apply.

Comment: Thank you for this. I put that in as an example, I am not actually setting the queryAction to an empty string. I am looking to set it to the string that will then be used by the $.ajax call in the 'data:' parameter field. Unfortunately, I am unable to change server side code.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `objectName` is in fact JSON data already. I might be wrong but I think this should work (with less code):

```
var jsonData = { 
    "name1": { 
        "queryName": "longname1", 
        "queryAction": "JSONtoSend" 
    }, 
    "name2": { 
        "queryName": "longname2", 
        "queryAction": "JSONtoSend" 
    },  
};

//Post with AJAX
$.post('url.php', jsonData, 'json')
.done(function(data) {
    alert('Succes!')
})
.fail(function(data) {
    alert('Failed!')
});

//This does the same (Post with AJAX)
$.ajax({
    url: 'url.php', //Get action attribute of the form
    type: "POST",
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: "json",
    .done(function() { //or success: function() {
            alert( "success" );
    })
    .fail(function() { //or error: function() {
            alert( "error" );
    })
    .always(function() { //or beforeSend: function() {
            alert( "complete" );
    });
});
```

Comment: This is valid, and would work - but maybe the resource he's requesting requires an object in a different form (which is why he's trying to chop it up with a `for`)

Comment: @DeeMac - I have a number of different JSON queries that I am looking to store. One for each name.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but as pointed out by others there are many issues with your code, but i think you want to execute ajax call one after the other iteratively. if that is what you want then take a look at jQuery deffered -docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).Hope that helps

Comment: My mistake, the $.ajax call should be included in the For statement.

Comment: @SimonHarper take a look at this (http://aameer.github.io/articles/two-level-ajax-in-a-loop/), maybe it will help. Moreover just to clarify what kind of data do you want to feed to ajax can you state an example